# How to make the cell of a grid as long as as entire grid

Tags: html, css, grid

Code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.prova {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

width: 100%;
background-color: none;
overflow: auto;
position: fixed;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="prova">1</div>
  <div class="prova">2</div>
  <div class="prova">3</div>
  <div class="prova">4</div>
  <div class="prova">5</div>
  <div class="prova">6</div>
  <div class="prova">7</div>
  <div class="prova">8</div>
  <div class="prova">9</div>
  <div class="prova">10</div>
  <div class="prova">11</div>
  <div class="prova">12</div>
</div>
```

As you can see here, in the last row of the grid there are 4 cells but I'd like them to become just one long cell, or to add another cell below them as bis as I just said!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use `grid-column: span 4;` on your last child to make it span all columns:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.prova {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.wrapper div:last-child {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="prova">1</div>
  <div class="prova">2</div>
  <div class="prova">3</div>
  <div class="prova">4</div>
  <div class="prova">5</div>
  <div class="prova">6</div>
  <div class="prova">7</div>
  <div class="prova">8</div>
  <div class="prova">9</div>
  <div class="prova">10</div>
  <div class="prova">11</div>
  <div class="prova">12</div>
  <div class="prova">13</div>
</div>
```